# Putting a UPR page into a set of tables with SQL

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to put a UPR pages into a set of tables for a database, so far I have come up with the following tables

- UPR:
  CODE,
  NAME,
  STRUCTURES,
  APPENDICES,
  DOCUMENTS
- STRUCTURES:
  STR_NAME,
  STR_CODE
- APPENDICES:
  APP_NAME,
  APP_CODE
- DOCUMENTS:
  DOC_NAME,
  DOC_CODE

these tables are going to be used to store each part of the UPR's how ever I am having trouble trying to work out how to get all of the tables to link up so that they will all work together and have one way of pulling all relavent appendices, documents and structures together for one UPR code. I have a feeling I might be being blind here but cannot see to work out a way of doing this, any help would be hugely appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: not 100% sure what you are looking for here, but I think you want to take structures, appendices and documents OUT of table UPR, and add upr code to each of the 3 other tables. You might watn to add a sequence field too so that that you know what order each section should appear in.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have removed the three from the UPR table and have added a UPR code to the structures, appendices and documents table. Currently working around this new idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE UPR
(
    CODE  NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
    NAME  VARCHAR2(50)
)
;


ALTER TABLE UPR ADD CONSTRAINT PK_UPR 
    PRIMARY KEY (CODE) 
 USING INDEX 
;

    -- -------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE STRUCTURES
(
    ID        NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
    UPR       NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
    SEQUENCE  NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
    NAME      VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
)
;


ALTER TABLE STRUCTURES ADD CONSTRAINT PK_STRUCTURES 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
 USING INDEX 
;

ALTER TABLE STRUCTURES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_STRUCTURES_UPR 
    FOREIGN KEY (UPR) REFERENCES UPR (CODE)
;
```

The structure of 'Appendix' and 'Document' would then follow the same pattern as 'Structures.

Does that help ?

**edit**

To build a complete UPR you would then do something like

```
SELECT S.NAME, D.SEQUENCE FROM STRUCTURES S WHERE CODE = :SomeCode
UNION SELECT A.NAME, D.SEQUENCE FROM APPENDIX A WHERE A.UPR = S.CODE
UNION SELECT D.NAME, D.SEQUENCE FROM DOCUMENT D WHERE D.UPR = S.CODE
ORDER BY 2
```

By the way ? What is a UPR? :)

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for this. It seems to work, I am just wondering now on a way to bring all of these tables together in some way to show a complete record of one 'UPR', showing all of the UPR's documents, appendices and structures? Many many thanks for your help! (I cant up vote yet)

Comment: They are the user policy records guys are keen to throw them all into a database!Thank you very much for your help you have saved me! many thanks!